# Problems when names have functions and spaces in them

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem regarding spaces in columm names. I have to give a columm the name 'MIN MAX'

But when later accessing the name, the name is seen as 2 functions, MIN and MAX and not as a name

I tried to use the following code for MIN:

```
'Min' AS ['MIN MAX']
```

The code is even marked as text when giving the name and later on as well, but still I get error messages, reffering to the incorrect use of the functions.

I myself would just leave out the spaces and the problem is solved, but since it is required by the bojective statement, I have to use the space.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, single quotes surround text. Double quotes surround identifiers. In MySQL, by default *backticks* surround identifiers.

To create a column named either way, use backticks.

```
create table test (
  `min max` integer not null,
  `min` integer not null
);
```

Also use backticks in SELECT statements.

```
select `min max` from test;
select `min` as `min max` from test;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this in mysql

```
SELECT 'Min' AS 'MIN MAX'
```